# org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Cannot find Velocity template for URL

Tags: spring, velocity

Velocity Configuration with spring,I am missing some configuration. Please tell me why it is happening so.
Getting the below error when I hit my url.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet springDispatcher threw exception
org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Cannot find Velocity template for URL [layout.vm]: Did you specify the correct resource loader path?; nested exception is org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'layout.vm'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView.checkResource(VelocityLayoutView.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:438)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:186)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:103)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1211)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1160)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
```

spring-context.xml

```
<bean id="velocityConfig"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
<property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/" />
</bean>

<!-- View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. 
If you need different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the 
resource bundle resolver. -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
<property name="cache" value="true" />
<property name="prefix" value="" />
<property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
</bean>
```

I'm getting the below exception when the velocityconfig is dropped.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfig] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:367)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView.autodetectVelocityEngine(VelocityView.java:239)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView.initApplicationContext(VelocityView.java:225)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
at org.springframework.beans.fact
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you will be able to achieve the Velocity configuration using your `viewResolver` alone.

Modify your prefix to the one mentioned in your resourceLoaderPath and it should be fine (didn't test it myself)

```
<property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/velocity/</value></property>
```

Also, you could drop the `velocityConfig` tag altogether.

Comment: I think the `velocityconfig` is required because when I dropped the `velocityConfig` tag I got some exception. That exception is also given in the post. Take a look at the post again.

Comment: Sorry about that. btw, did prefixing the path to your templates work?

Answer (score -2):

you should use

```
(bean id="ViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver")
```

not

```
(bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver")
```

this bean use 'layout.vm'，i also have this problem.